# How to customize system preferences settings for all users

Tags: customization, user-profile, gnome-settings-daemon

Does anybody know how to apply a customized user settings to other `existing` or `new` users?. Something like a customized preferences settings for system wide so that everybody posses those settings and below will explain in clear what I actually ment.

On every machine I will install the following:

```
Eclipse
Mysql Query Browser and Admin
Mysql Workbench
Oracle VirtualBox
Thunderbird
-----------
-----------
-----------
```

If I install them by apt, this will automatically create shortcuts in `Applications` but when I build them from source or extract the tar ball, I will have to add `New Item` at it's relevant place going to `System-->Preferences-->Main Menu` to make them available as a shortcuts and this settings are applied only for the account I login and perform them. How could I make this preferences settings for complete system wide which applies for all users? or if there is a way to apply a customized user settings to other users will also be ok. Any hint please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different kinds of system preferences that are stored in different ways. So answering your broad question is difficult, but here's the answer to the specific question:

When you use the menu editor to create new shortcuts, it works by creating [desktop files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html#introduction) which get placed in the user's`/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/` directory. This will only add it to the menu of the user used to create the menu item. For the menu item to be accesable system-wide, you can put the desktop file in `/usr/local/share/applications/`

You could find the desktop file created by the menu editor and move it, or you could just create a file under `/usr/local/share/applications/` manually. Here's a sample file, `terminator.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
Comment=Multiple terminals in one window
Exec=terminator
Icon=terminator
Name=Terminator
Type=Application
```

Replace the values with those appropriate for your application.

Comment: You've given nice hint or probably answer, I could see come progress, let me check it thoroughly and I'll get back to accept your answer!. Thanks!

Comment: I could not see `applications` directory under `/usr/local/share`. Should I create it?

Comment: I could see `applications` upto the edition lucid. But in new editions(11.04, 11.10) I couldn't see the directory, any more idea?

Comment: Actually I upgraded from karmic to lucid and the path was `/usr/local/share/applications` as you said. Probably the path is changed from 10.04 onwards and is `/usr/share/applications` where I could see many applications. This would be enough for my requirement for now. You're awesome!!!. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. `/usr/share/applications` is where distribution packages install these files. Generally, you want to keep files handled by the package manager and files you create separate. `/usr/local/share/applications` might not exist in a default install, but you can create it yourself. It's not something that is 100% necessary, but it is very good practice.